# Why does gnumake remake the intermediate file?

Tags: gnu-make

I have a very simple makefile as below:

```
.PHONY: clean all

CC              = /home/utils/gcc-5.2.0/bin/g++
CFLAGS          = -Wall -Werror -fPIC 

SRC             = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ             = $(subst .c,.o,$(SRC))

.INTERMEDIATE: $(OBJ)

all: test.so

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

test.so: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -shared $^ -o $@

clean:
    @rm -f *.o *~ *.so
```

I have only two files in the same directory: a.c and b.c
When I execute "make all", I got the following which is perfect.

```
/home/utils/gcc-5.2.0/bin/g++ -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -o a.o -c a.c
/home/utils/gcc-5.2.0/bin/g++ -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -o b.o -c b.c
/home/utils/gcc-5.2.0/bin/g++ -shared a.o b.o -o test.so
rm a.o b.o
```

However, if I do: 
    touch a.c; make all

I got the same make execution sequence as above which is not what I expected. There is no dependency between a.c and b.c. What I expect is:

```
/home/utils/gcc-5.2.0/bin/g++ -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -o a.o -c a.c
/home/utils/gcc-5.2.0/bin/g++ -shared a.o b.o -o test.so
rm a.o
```

I don't understand why b.c is compiled again. According to gnumake manual:

The first difference is what happens if the intermediate file does not exist. If an ordinary file b does not exist, and make considers a target that depends on b, it invariably creates b and then updates the target from b. But if b is an intermediate file, then make can leave well enough alone. It won’t bother updating b, or the ultimate target, unless some prerequisite of b is newer than that target or there is some other reason to update that target.

b.o is an intermediate file, it should not be compiled again since b.c has not changed. 
What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

If `b.o` is not recompiled, then `test.so` cannot be created because it depends on `b.o`.  You can't create the shared library from `a.o` and `b.o` if `b.o` was deleted.

If you were trying to create a static library then you could use make's special archive syntax to replace `a.o` without needing to recompile `b.o`, but that's not possible unless you use the archive special syntax, and it can't be done for shared libraries such as you're trying to build here.

There's a reason these `.o` files are not considered intermediate by default, and forcing them to be by adding the `.INTERMEDIATE` target doesn't mean you can avoid rebuilding them.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of understand b.o is indeed needed to build the shared libraries. I was not very clear on how make treats a user-defined intermediate file and what is its process to overwrite that.

Answer (score 0):

Your difficulty stems from the fact that what you mean by *an intermediate file*
is not what GNU Make means; but the `.INTERMEDIATE` special target allows you to insist
that `a.o` and `b.o`, which in your makefile are not intermediate files in GNU Make's
sense, shall be treated as if they *are* intermediate *in GNU Make's sense*, and
then you're taken aback by the consequences.

What *you* mean by *F is an intermediate file* is: *F is a prerequisite of target T and
F itself has prerequisites*. Thus `a.o` and `b.o` are intermediate with respect to
`test.so` because they are prerequisites of that target and themselves have the
respective prerequisites `a.c` and b.c`.

In your sense of *intermediate*, making the target `test.so` does not call for
(`a.o`|`b.o`) to be remade unless it is older than (`a.c|b.c`). So you are taken aback by the fact
that when `a.o` and `b.o` are made `.INTERMEDIATE`, GNU Make *always deletes them*
when it makes `test.so`:

> b.o is an intermediate file, it should not be compiled again since b.c has not changed. What did I miss?

Chiefly you missed [10.4 Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html)

> Ordinarily, a file cannot be intermediate if it is mentioned in the makefile as a target or prerequisite.
>   However, you can explicitly mark a file as intermediate by listing it as a prerequisite of the special target .INTERMEDIATE.
>   This takes effect even if the file is mentioned explicitly in some other way.

So, `a.o` and `b.o` would ordinarily *not* be intermediate in GNU Make's sense,
because they are mentioned in your makefile as prequisites of `test.so`. But you can
make them be treated as intermediate, in GNU Make's sense, by listing them as prerequisites of `.INTERMEDIATE` - as you did.

What GNU Make means by *intermediate* is more technical than what you mean and
is explained in the same section of the manual:

> Sometimes a file can be made by a sequence of implicit rules. For example, a file n.o
>   could be made from n.y by running first Yacc and then cc. Such a sequence is called a chain.
>
> If the file n.c exists, or is mentioned in the makefile, no special searching is required:
>   make finds that the object file can be made by C compilation from n.c; later on, when
>   considering how to make n.c, the rule for running Yacc is used. Ultimately both n.c and n.o are updated.
>
> However, even if n.c does not exist and is not mentioned, make knows how to envision it as the
>   missing link between n.o and n.y! **In this case, n.c is called an intermediate file**.
>   Once make has decided to use the intermediate file, it is entered in the data base as
>   if it had been mentioned in the makefile, along with the implicit rule that says how to create it.

(My emphasis). More briefly, if Make is required to make target *output*, and discovers a file *input* such
that:

- It has no explicit rule for making *output* from *input*, but -
- It knows a sequence of *implicit* (a.k.a *builtin*) rules by
  which a file *stage* that is not a target or prerequisite in the makefile can
  be made from *input*, and from which *output* can be made, then it will adopt this
  sequence of rules to make *output* from *input* via *stage*, and *stage* will be
  an *intermediate* file.

Crucially, since *stage* is not one of your targets, or a prerequisite of any of them, Make
knows that it is merely a *disposable by-product* of making *output* from *input*,
and therefore can be deleted when it has served that purpose.

Here is a simple example project involving files that are really intermediate in GNU Make's sense.
We have some [`yacc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) source `yacc.y` and [`lex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) source `lex.l`, in the project directory,
and we want to build a parser from them, `parse`, with the following makefile:

**Makefile**

```
YFLAGS := -d
OBJS := yacc.o lex.o

.PHONY: all clean

all: parse

parse: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) parse $(OBJS)
```

It runs like:

```
$ make
yacc -d yacc.y
mv -f y.tab.c yacc.c
cc    -c -o yacc.o yacc.c
lex  -t lex.l > lex.c
cc    -c -o lex.o lex.c
cc yacc.o lex.o -o parse
rm lex.c yacc.c
```

Now you see that Make, using its catalogue of implicit rules, figured out
that `yacc.o` could be made by compiling the non-existent C source file
`yacc.c`, and that `yacc.c` could be produced from the existing source file
`yacc.y` by running `yacc -d yacc.y; mv -f y.tab.c yacc.c`. Likewise, it figured out that `lex.o`
could be made by compiling the nonexistent C source `lex.c`, and that `lex.c`
could be made from `lex.l` by running `lex -t lex.l > lex.c`. Then `parse` is
made from `yacc.o` and `lex.o` by the routine linkage that the makefile
specifies.

But your makefile says nothing whatever about `yacc.c` and `lex.c`. As far as
you have told Make, it does not matter to you whether or not such files ever exist.
They are *intermediate files*, merely stages in the `.y -> .o` and `.l -> .o` productions. So
when Make is done with them:

```
rm lex.c yacc.c
```

Then if you:

```
$ touch yacc.y
```

and again:

```
$ make
yacc -d yacc.y
mv -f y.tab.c yacc.c
cc    -c -o yacc.o yacc.c
cc yacc.o lex.o -o parse
rm yacc.c
```

only `yacc.o` gets remade for the linkage of `parse`, and the *one*
intermediate file `yacc.c` that was generated this time is deleted.

**Bottom line**

Your object files are not intermediate in GNU Make's sense and you don't
want them to be treated as if they are. This is normal for object files.
So remove `.INTERMEDIATE: $(OBJ)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @L.Z Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Just one comment: this statement is not really correct: _It has no rule for making `output` from `input`_.  Perhaps you mean no _explicit_ rule, but clearly make has to have some rule to build `output` else you'll get an error.  What intermediate files really are is this: if make is considering `output` as a target, and it sees that `output` depends on `input` **and `input` does not exist**, but make can envision how `input` could be created as an intermediate file and it sees that `input` itself would not need to be rebuilt, then make won't rebuild it.

Comment: Intermediate targets are not so useful anymore (IMO): they used to be helpful when disk space was expensive as they allowed you to delete files that were needed to build things but weren't needed to update things.  The canonical example is a static library: you can replace a single `.o` file in an archive (static library) without rebuilding the entire archive from scratch.  This allows you to delete all the `.o` files (saving disk space) then rebuild a `.o` for just the files that changed and replace them in the library without rebuilding, or storing, all the `.o`'s that didn't change.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, explicit rule is what I meant. Have made explicit explicit.